# How to merge two tables where one is parent of the other?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to merge two tables together and maintain the fact that one is the child of the other table. i want to show that it has a parent while still maintaining the parent with its unique values.

here's what i have in relations:
subdomain.domain_id is related to (you guessed it) domain.id

my table examples

domain:

```
id | name | description | validator | need | need_amount
---|------|-------------|-----------|------|-------------
5  | prog | this iss..  | 6         | low  | 5
```

subdomain

```
id | name | description | validator | domain_id | need | need_amount
---|------|-------------|-----------|-----------|------|------------
5  | java | java is...  | 10        | 5         | high | 10
6  | c++  | c++...      | 9         | 5         | high | 10
```

i want to be able to see

```
id | domain_name | subdomain_name | description | validator | need | need_amount
---|-------------|----------------|-------------|-----------|------|-------------
5  | prog        | null           | this iss..  | 6         | low  | 5
5  | prog        | java           | this is...  | 10        | high | 10
6  | prog        | c++            | this is..   | 9         | high | 10
```

OR like this, (ideally the one above)

```
id | name         | description | validator | need | need_amount
---|--------------|-------------|-----------|------|------------
5  | prog         | this iss..  | 6         | low  | 5
5  | prog - java  | java is...  | 10        | high | 10
6  | prog - c++   | c++...      | 9         | high | 10
```

Any ideas??? is it possible? Thanks!

Thanks to @Pradeep

```
SELECT id,
       name AS domain_name,
       NULL AS subdomain_name,
       description,
       validator,
       need,
       need_amount
FROM   domain 
UNION ALL
SELECT a.id,
       b.name AS domain_name,
       a.name            AS subdomain_name,
       a.description,
       a.validator,
       a.need,
       a.need_amount
FROM   subdomain a join domain b on a.domain_id=b.id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this.

```
SELECT id,
       name AS domain_name,
       NULL AS subdomain_name,
       description,
       validator,
       need,
       need_amount
FROM   parent 
UNION ALL
SELECT a.id,
       b.domain_name AS domain_name,
       a.name            AS subdomain_name,
       a.description,
       a.validator,
       a.need,
       a.need_amount
FROM   child a join parent b on a.domain_id=b.domain_id
```

Comment: thanks for reply. seems very close! but I'm getting zeros on name for the children and was getting null on description for parent so i changed null to description. any ideas?EDIT: JUST saw update on ur post let me try.

Comment: @jsan which name you are  getting zeros  subdomain r domain??

Comment: looks very close but instead of 'prog -' i wanted to see the parent name. and in subdomain_name for child i want to see child name. that make sense? so i changed description as subdomain_name to name as subdomain_name which worked out but now the only thing i need is the parent name in the domain_name for child

Comment: would have to be something like select domain.name from domain, subdomain where domain.id = subdomain.domain_id but where do i place this?

Comment: @jsan - sorry i didnt check domain_id in child

Comment: ok now it worked!! thanks @Pradeep . but it was giving ambiguous errors so i had to clarify for the child.